# Using Alternative Browser to Record Web Performance with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, internet-explorer-11, performance-testing, web-performance

By default, Visual Studio 2015 uses the built-in Internet Explorer 11 to record web performance. Is there a way to change it to another browser?

Comment: Has your question been answered? If not then please [edit] it to make it clearer. If it has been answered then please read about [accepting answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 2):

No. Visual Studio relies upon an add-in (an extension) to Internet Explorer to do the work. As far as I know the interface between that add-in and Internet Explorer is not publically defined.

There is a work around. You can use Fiddler to record what happens when using another browser and then export that recording as a ".webtest" file.

Comment: Thanks for this information. As of 2019 Internet Explorer is not categorized as a web browser by Microsoft and Visual Studio is deprecating web tests while not offering any reasonable alternative replacement tool. However, Fiddler does the job as expected.